# Convert NSDate from NSString issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I have an issue with my date conversion, which I didn't succeed in finding a solution. This gonna makes me crazy.
So I retreive a date from a REST Web Service, under a string type and when I try to convert the date to NSDate, I lose one year.

Here is the code :

```
- (NSDate *)convertISOToDate:(NSString *) dateString {
    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate  *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return date;
}
```

When I debug, I have this in input : dateString __NSCFString *  @"**2017**-12-30T11:51:46+0100"

And on the date object : date   __NSDate *  **2016**-12-30 11:51:46 CET 0x1dd3e950

Anyone get an idea on the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `"yyyy"` instead of `"YYYY"`. `"YYYY"` is weekly based year.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ];
```